# How to enter session code number in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.8

After register redirect to this page.

I want enter this code. (Of course mobile number and the code save in database and send a sms to mobile).

How to enter session code number?

[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SarPu.jpg)

web.php

```
Route::get('/code', 'HomeController@code')->name('code');
Route::post('/send', 'HomeController@send')->name('send');
```

RegisterController.php

```
public function register(Request $request, User $user)
{
    $code = rand(10000,99999);
    $user = \App\User::create([
        'first_name' => $request->first_name,
    .
    .
    .
    .
return redirect()->route('code',['mobile'=>$request->mobile]);
```

HomeController.php

```
public function code()
{
    return view('Home.send');
}

    public function send(Request $request)
{
    $mobile = $request->session()->get('mobile');
    $user = User::whereCode($request->code)
        ->whereMobile($mobile)
        ->firstOrFail();
    if($user){
        $user->verification_code = 1;
        $user->save();
        alert()->success('ok');
        return redirect()->back();
    } else {
        alert()->error('error');
        return redirect()->back();
    }
}
```

send.blad,php

```
<form action="{{ route('send') }}" method="post">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="code">Code</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="code" id="code">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" id="btn-ok">OK</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

I get this error

[404](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FOWO1.png)

I have `verification_code` in `users` table. I want In case of enter true code and mobile number, `verification_code` change to 1

Comment: When accessing where you get `404`?

Comment: After enter  code in textbox and press ok button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look on [Retrieving Single Models - Not Found Exceptions](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#retrieving-single-models).

> The firstOrFail method will retrieve the first result of the query;
>   however, if no result is found, a 
>   Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException will be thrown.
>
> If the exception is not caught, a 404 HTTP response is automatically sent
>   back to the user. It is not necessary to write explicit checks to
>   return 404 responses when using these methods.

So, you can try catch the exeption:

```
try {
    $mobile = $request->session()->get('mobile');
    $user = User::whereCode($request->code)
        ->whereMobile($mobile)
        ->firstOrFail();

    $user->verification_code = 1;
    $user->save();

} catch (Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException $e) {
    return redirect()->back()->with('alert', 'error');
}

return redirect()->back()->with('success', 'ok');
```

Or otherwise use `first` instead of `firstOrFail`, which will return `null` if there is no record that meets the where conditions:

```
$mobile = $request->session()->get('mobile');
$user = User::whereCode($request->code)
    ->whereMobile($mobile)
    ->first();

if(empty($user)){
    return redirect()->back()->with('alert', 'error');
} 

$user->verification_code = 1;
$user->save();
return redirect()->back()->with('success', 'ok');
```